# Why is the attribute also append to the child node?

Tags: xml, vbscript, attributes

I want to create an XML file like below, but the problem is that by adding the attribute to the `startMethod` it is also append to the child node `globalSettings`

Code:

```vb
' Build SOAP Request
Set objSOAPXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")
objSOAPXML.async = False

' Create Root Element: Web Service
Set objWebService = objSOAPXML.CreateElement("startMethod")
objWebService.setAttribute "xmlns", xmlns
objSOAPXML.documentElement.childNodes(0).appendChild objWebService

' Create Web Service Request
Set objGlobalSettings = objSOAPXML.CreateElement("globalSettings")
objWebService.appendChild objGlobalSettings
```

Expected:

```xml
<startMethod xmlns="http://localhost:62324/">
    <globalSettings>
        ...
    </globalSettings>
</startMethod>
```

But the output is:

```xml
<startMethod xmlns="http://localhost:62324/">
    <globalSettings xmlns="">
           ...
    </globalSettings>
</startMethod>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although namespace declarations have the syntactic form of attributes, they are semantically quite different.

By setting `xmlns="startMethod"` on the root element, you're saying you want the element to me in a particular namespace. You haven't said that you want the child element to be in a namespace, so it isn't in one; and because it is in no namespace, it has to be serialized with `xmlns=""` to cancel the namespace declaration on the parent element.

If you want all the elements to be in the same namespace then you should create them all in this namespace.

Comment: Yes, Great! Worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked. The convention on StackOverflow is that you don't need to say thanks, but you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick/check mark next to the answer.